# Как реализовать возможность перевода числа из 10-й СС в любую СС до 8-й

Tags: c#, системы-счисления, преобразование

Помогите написать код для перевода системы числа из 10-й системы счисления в любую другую до 8-ой. 
Писал похожий код:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), system = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        string s = null;
        s = number % system + s;
        number /= system;
        label1.Text = string.Format(("{0}, = {1}"), system, s);
```

Но, работоспособность у него не присутствует.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = 10;
int sys = 2;

List<int> result = new List<int>();

while (num > 0)
{
    result.Add(num % sys);
    num /= sys;
}

result.Reverse();
Console.WriteLine("({0:d})_{1}", sys, string.Join("", result));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score -2):

Работоспособность не присутствует -- делаешь немного не так  =)
например стоило число приводить к типу строки String при записи в неё

```
S = Convert.ToString( (number%system) ) + S;
```

Да, здравая мысль реализовать **в цикле:**
исходное число делить нацело на делитель=(основание СС возведённое в степень равную номеру(0,1,2... N) вычисляемого сейчас разряда выходного значения); остаток деления записать в разряд выходного значения, целочисленный результат оставить для следующей итерации цикла; делитель умножить на осн.СС (для след.итерации); повторить.

Таким образом вычислить выходное значение по одному знаку, начиная с конца (с младших разрядов к старшим).